# Python: How do I replace span tag with a formatted span tag and return resulting page via beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning how to use beautiful soup, I'm trying to parse the search page from usda food database and change the entire span tag in div, class 'btn-group' to the modified one I have formatted in variable: `search_output`. After that, execute the modified page, and then read the page result(This is what I mainly need help with).

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

class Global:
    search_input = ''

##### Start function ##### SEARCH: RED APPLE as test
def search_food():
    Global.search_input = input("What food do you want to search for?")
search_food()

##### Formatted search span replacement #####
search_output = f'<input type="text" class="searchbox ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="For example: raw broccoli" value="{Global.search_input}" title="Enter search terms" name="qlookup" id="qlookup" size="180" autocomplete="off">'

##### URL #####
my_url = 'https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list?SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN=89dea722-0ff1-487e-9668-f42d2f61d19e&SYNCHRONIZER_URI=%2Fndb%2Fsearch%2Flist&qt=&qlookup=&ds=SR&manu='

##### Download the page #####
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

##### Html parsing #####
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
search_container = page_soup.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'btn-group'})
tag = search_container.find('span', attrs={'class': 'value'})
tag.string = search_output
tag

##### Resulting search page / Haven't gotten this far #####
#s_result_page = #resulting page
#uClient_result2 = uReq(s_result_page)
#page_html2 = uClient_result2.read()
#uClient_result2.close()
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workout_db.py", line 25, in <module>
    tag = search_container.find('span', attrs={'class': 'value'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Ultimately my goal is to take the resulting page, example:`https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list?SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN=38fe7d59-b22b-46ec-9cf6-cd9321739158&SYNCHRONIZER_URI=%2Fndb%2Fsearch%2Flist&qt=&qlookup=red+apple&ds=SR&manu=` parse it, make it so `my_url` is the most relevant resulting hyperlink to my search query... and then finally read `my_url` to parse nutrition info.

The main problem I face is on the top half, above the code but felt I needed to explain what I'm trying to do to paint a clearer picture. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error you mentioned in the question is a result of the `page_soup.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'btn-group'})` not actually finding an element. So the value of `search_container` is `None`.

Comment: You don't need to actually fill out the form and submit it to perform a search. So you can bypass the first step by simply performing the search in the initial request:

e.g. `uReq('https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list/?qlookup=Lamb')` (might I suggest using the excellent [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org) to perform requests, it's a bit more user friendly.